# Java add on to the message of the custom exception, at a place where, a particular function throws the exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that throws my custom Exception.
My custom Exception:

```
public class IllegalEntryException extends Exception
{
    public IllegalEntryException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and my method:

```
    public Order(String[] value) throws IllegalEntryException
    {
        String timeString = value[0];
        try
        {
            this.time = Integer.parseInt(timeString);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalEntryException("First entry of each column, time must be int, found at row ");
        }
    }
```

Now on the method which actually calls this function (which is also a constructor) I have access to a variable which tracks the row number of the file on which this error occurs. I want to add on this row number to the message when the exception was thrown (i.e. in the constructor) so that when I handle it finally over there the row number is also printed.
Something like:

```
try
{
    calltoFunction(); // exception is thrown
    // somehow add the row number to the message
}
catch {}//Handle the exception over here
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry I was looking for something like this:

```
                try
                {
                    Order order = new Order(values);
                }
                catch(IllegalEntryException e)
                {
                    String error = e.getMessage() + "row_no";
                    System.err.println(error);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, you can access it's stacktrace (which also contains all method calls on the stack, including their class name and the line which caused the exception) by calling:

```
    e.getStackTrace();
```

Furthermore,

```
    e.printStackTrace();
```

will print said stacktrace to the System.out stream, which should suffice for debugging purposes.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve by having the row number in the catch block, but you could try getting the whole stacktrace as a string by the following means:

```
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter );
    String stackTrace = stringWriter.toString();
```

From the string `stackTrace`, you could then figure out your row number.